# How to "EnforceConstraints" to avoid linq errors?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2008, system.type

I'm working on a sample from the book I bought. And, for unknown reason, I get the following error message " **Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Type'.  'Where' not found.**"

The VS2008 help says that I need to add System.Linq and System.Collections namespaces to solve the issue. Unfortunatelly, I still get the same error message. In MSDN forum, it said that I need to set EnforceConstraints to true;

I would like to know what's "EnforceConstraints" and how can I do it.

Thanks.

---

## Here is the code

using System; 
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Castle.Windsor;
using Castle.Windsor.Configuration.Interpreters;
using Castle.Core.Resource;
using System.Reflection;
using Castle.Core;
using System.Collections;

namespace WebUI
{
    public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        WindsorContainer Container;

```
    public WindsorControllerFactory()
    {
        //Instatiate a container, taking configuration from web.conf
        Container = new WindsorContainer(
            new XmlInterpreter(new ConfigResource("Castle"))
            );

        //Also register all the controller types as transient
        var controllerTypes =
            from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType()
            where typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t)
            select t;
        foreach (Type t in controllerTypes)
            Container.AddComponentWithLifestyle(t.FullName, t, LifestyleType.Transient);
        }

        //Constructs the controller instance needed to service each request
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType)
    {
        return (IController)Container.Resolve(controllerType);
    }    

    }//The constructor
}
```

---

The sample is on page 98.

the book is "Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework"/Steven Sanderson/APress ISBN-13 (pbk): 978-1-4302-1007-8

Comment: Can you post the code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line:

```
from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType()
```

you are missing a 's' at the end of `GetTypes()`. This should solve the problem, as `GetType()` is returning a single `Type` instance, whereas `GetTypes()` returns an array of `Type` objects.

Answer (score 1):

That suggests you're trying to do something like:

```
Type type = typeof(int);
var methods = from method in type
              select method;
```

There's no "Select" method defined in `System.Type` or as an extension method - basically a `Type` isn't a valid data source for a LINQ query. Could you post the full example (and ideally which book it comes from)? It may well just be a typo - either in what you've copied or in the book itself.

EDIT: Now you've posted the code (which should be in a question edit, not an answer btw) I can see it's just a typo. Instead of this:

```
from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType()
```

you should have

```
from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
```

Note the "s" at the end :)

`GetType()` returns the type of the object (i.e. `typeof(Assembly)` or some subclass) whereas `GetTypes()` returns the collection of types within the assmebly. The latter is definitely what you want.

Comment: Thank very much (for everything, including how to ask and edit questions )